# SSRS E-mail report content based on user

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have a report for which I want to set up a data driven subscription. It needs to return different rows for different users and be automatically e-mailed to those different users as excel attachment. Say, for example, the report was based on one dataset and a column in that dataset was called [user]. I want the report e-mailed where UserA just gets the rows with UserA in the [user] column, UserB just gets the rows with UserB in the [user] column and so on.

I'm not sure how to configure a data-driven subscription to do this (or even whether it's possible). I'm sure this is not an unusual requirement. Are there any good step-by-step guides that can be recommended?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a user parameter and use this filter to filt dataset.